# Passing Parameters between 2 classes

Tags: java, javafx

I am making Twitch chat using twitch api wrapper and JavaFx. But I have a problem with passing parameters when getting a message in chat. I made a thread. It should work like this:

- 1) A programm launches
- 2) Starting new "Task"(new Thread in main method) to start a bot
- 3) Getting a message via onMessage method
- 4) Changing the label to the message text

The problem is that i can't understand how to pass Message String from onMessage method to Controller so I can change the label's text.

Here's the code:

**Bot class:**

```
public class Bot extends TwitchBot {
    public Bot() {           
    }
    public static String message2;
    @Override
    public void onMessage(User user, Channel channel, String message) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Message is:" + message);
        setMessage2(message);

    }

    private void setMessage2(String message) {
        message2 = message;
    } 
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller  implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Label labelChat;
    @FXML private TextArea textArea;
    @FXML private GridPane gridPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {    
        System.out.println("MADE");  
    }

    public void messagePrint(String message) {
        System.out.println("LABEL!!!");
        labelChat.setText(message);    
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {   
    public static Controller c;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("Launched");
//        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));    
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller c = loader.getController();
        Main.c = c;


        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");





        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 550));
        primaryStage.show();




    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwitchBot bot = new Bot();
        bot.connect();
        bot.joinChannel("#artek_tv");   
        Task task = new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {    
                bot.start();
                return null;
            }
        };

        new Thread(task).start();

        Task task2 = new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {

                c.messagePrint(Bot.message2);
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task2).start();    
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to remove those api keys...

Comment: But they work, i just need to somehow get things right with javafx

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me - you don't want someone to steal your API keys!!

Comment: 1. In a JavaFX Application, don't put anything in `main()` other than a call to `launch()`

Comment: 2. Don't make things `static` just to make it easy to get access to them. `static` is about *scope*, not *access*. To access an instance variable or method, you need a reference to the object that owns it.

Comment: can you fix my code please? I cant think about new ways to solve it

Comment: 3. Don't change the UI from a background thread.

Comment: There are too many different things wrong here: the question is too broad. Start simpler so you can address one issue at a time.

Comment: How to get access to instance of the controller?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set the message using setMessage2() right?
Then why don't you access `Label labelChat`in that method and set text using `Platform.runLater(Runnable)`

Comment: `private void setMessage2(String message) {
 Platform.runLater(() -> {
   Class-obj.labelChat.setText(message);
 });
} `  and make  `@FXML private Label labelChat;` to `@FXML public Label labelChat;`

Comment: It says that non-static variable labelChat cant be referenced from a static context

Comment: Check your scope.

Comment: You are trying to access a non-static variable i.e `Label labelChat` from main method which is obviously a static. Either make `labelChat` `static` or call `messagePrint()` from non-static method.

Comment: You can't make `labelChat` static, as it's `@FXML`-injected.